# jQuery.history и поисковые системы

Tags: jquery, history

Собственно, хотелось бы поинтересоваться, как  реагируют поисковые системы на jQuery.history? То есть, если у меня навигация по сайту происходит в виде ссылок: `http://mysite.com/#menu/add`,   `http://mysite.com/#menu/edit`, ну и так далее. Будет ли поисковик индексировать такие страницы?

Comment: Никто не сталкивался?

Comment: не совсем ясен вопрос, как у тебя выглядят сами ссылки на сайте? используешь ли ты аякс или просто скрываешь/показываешь часть контента?

Comment: ссылки выглядят в виде:  
    
    <a href="#menu/add">ADD</a>
    <a href="#menu/edit">EDIT</a>    

И да, я использую аякс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

поисковики твои ссылки не съедят, единственно что для гугла можно специально настроить такие адреса(ссылку на инфу не дам потому как сам не помню как туда забрёл), но если ты в серьёз намерен юзать аякс, то используй обычные ссылки и отменяй дефолтное поведение браузера на эти ссылки, юзай:

```
function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

в таком случае поисковики будут ходить по сайту как обычно и спокойно индексировать твои страницы

Comment: Спасиб. Как раз подумал о ссылках с href вида "/menu/add", а уже обработчиком сувать их в хэш. )  
И ещё вопрос на засыпку: вроде как, если ссылки будут вида: mysite.com/#!/menu/add   то есть, после шарпа ставить восклицательный знак, то поисковикам это сигнал типа, есть ещё ссыли с таким же прямым адресом: mysite.com/menu/add    Это так?

Comment: у гугла вроде через восклицательный знак индексация аякса, на счёт яндекса не в курсе  
по поводу прямого адреса я не в курсе, так как у меня в движке все ссылки относительно сделаны, поидее можешь спокойно его использовать, никаких проблем быть не должно

Comment: Спасибо. :)  
Будут ещё интересные варианты, предлагай. :) А пока +. )

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте `sitemap.xml`.